# Managing the AmazonDynamoDBClient

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I am a beginner to DynamoDB (using .NET).  Is there any guidance on how to manage the lifetime of AmazonDynamoDBClient?

I'd like to make it a Singleton to avoid any connection penalty associated with connecting, but is that a bad idea?  It works fine in dev - will this hold up to production?

Thanks all for any guidance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like all of the AWS client classes in the AWS SDK for .NET, the AmazonDynamoDBClient is thread safe for a particular region or endpoint. Feel free to create a single AmazonDynamoDBClient for each region you will be connecting to and then sharing it across threads.

Thanks!